# jquery image replace?

Tags: javascript, jquery

when click on More Button the picture of More button and Featured will be changed and when you click agin on the More button the image should be the same as what it was the first, but it isn't.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#buy_now').hide(); 
    $('#more').click(function() {
        $("#more-btn").attr("src", "http://kilrush.mobi/kil/GetAssetFile?fileId=77470");
        $("#featur-btn").attr("src", "http://kilrush.mobi/kil/GetAssetFile?fileId=77472");
        $('#buy_now').toggle();              
    });      
});
```

Comment: Could you show us some html as well? It seems like you are changing the `src` attribute of the buttons instead of the image.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. Please present in a clear way what you are trying to do. -1 until you refomulate your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to store the original source then restore it. Best approach is using `.toggle()` for the button and `.data` to store the original source:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var btnMore = $("#more-btn");
    var btnFeature = $("#featur-btn");
    btnMore.data("org_src", btnMore.attr("src"));
    btnFeature.data("org_src", btnFeature.attr("src"));
    $('#buy_now').hide();
    $('#more').toggle(function() {
        btnMore.attr("src", "http://kilrush.mobi/kil/GetAssetFile?fileId=77470");
        btnFeature.attr("src", "http://kilrush.mobi/kil/GetAssetFile?fileId=77472");
        $('#buy_now').show();
    }, function() {
        btnMore.attr("src", btnMore.data("org_src"));
        btnFeature.attr("src", btnFeature.data("org_src"));
        $('#buy_now').hide();
    });
});
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/Pujj4/1/). (with cute cats :))

Comment: +1. Yes .toggle() is the key. You can also specify the original image source in the 2nd toggle function directly like the 1st one without storing the source by calling .data().

Comment: Thanks @iTypist good point, but this still can be good example of using `.data()` plus it's more flexible this way e.g. if he want the original source elsewhere. :)